# MYSQL - If a field is empty my Select statement with wp_usermeta returns zero rows. Why?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join, select

I need a little help with my Select Statement. I trying to understand how to write select statements using the wp_users and wp_usermeta tables. I run this select statement:

```
SELECT  u.display_name, u.user_email,
   ma.meta_value AS Address,
   concat( '(',left(mm.meta_value,3) , ') ' , mid(mm.meta_value,4,3) , '-', right(mm.meta_value,4)) AS Mobile,
   concat( '(',left(mp.meta_value,3) , ') ' , mid(mp.meta_value,4,3) , '-', right(mp.meta_value,4)) AS Phone,
   mc2.meta_value AS City,
   ms.meta_value AS State,
   mz.meta_value AS Zip
FROM wp_users u 
JOIN wp_usermeta ma ON u.ID = ma.user_id AND ma.meta_key = 'Address'
JOIN wp_usermeta mm ON u.ID = mm.user_id AND mm.meta_key = 'mobile_number'
JOIN wp_usermeta mp ON u.ID = mp.user_id AND mp.meta_key = 'phone_number'
JOIN wp_usermeta mc2 ON u.ID = mc2.user_id AND mc2.meta_key = 'user_city'
JOIN wp_usermeta ms ON u.ID = ms.user_id AND ms.meta_key = 'user_state'
JOIN wp_usermeta mz ON u.ID = mz.user_id AND mz.meta_key = 'user_zip'
WHERE u.id = $user_id
```

If the phone_number field is blank the statement returns No Rows, if I add a phone number to the field it works. How can I get the query to return the results regardless of whether or not any of the none required fields are blank?

I reviewed the "Advanced Wordpress SQL Query" question and this was not the same. 2nd Question, are there any places where I can learn to better write queries using the Wordpress wp_usermeta table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just how `(inner) join`s work; if the join condition is not satisfied, the record is eliminated from the result set. Wherever you need to allow missing relations, you want `left join`s:

```
...
FROM wp_users u 
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ma ON u.ID = ma.user_id AND ma.meta_key = 'Address'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta mm ON u.ID = mm.user_id AND mm.meta_key = 'mobile_number'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta mp ON u.ID = mp.user_id AND mp.meta_key = 'phone_number'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta mc2 ON u.ID = mc2.user_id AND mc2.meta_key = 'user_city'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ms ON u.ID = ms.user_id AND ms.meta_key = 'user_state'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta mz ON u.ID = mz.user_id AND mz.meta_key = 'user_zip'
...
```